# Protect post route in node express and mongodb api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, backend

I made an api that contains an array of object.
But I don't want user can post data to it.
So, I created a secret key and store it inside .env variable.
Now, when I want to post the data to the api. I have to pass that key along with content in the body using postman.
[image]
This is the code for that.

```
router.post('/items', async (req, res) => {
    const {name, image, token} = req.body;
   if(token !== process.env.API_TOKEN){
   return res
            .status(403)
            .send({error: 'You are not allowed to add data});
}
    if(!name || !image ) {
        return res
            .status(422)
            .send({error: 'There is no name and image'});
    }

    try {
        const item = new Item({name, image});
        await item.save();
        res.send(item);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(422).send({error: error.message});
    }
})
```

Now I want to put these keys in Headers instead of what I am doing right now.
How should I do that using postman and access that key inside our app?

If I send my key like this.

1. Is it a right way of doing that?
2. How I access that key inside our app and then check using if statement with our env key.
   [image]
   Please anyone help me with this one

Comment: have a look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-jwt-expressjs and https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken among others. For Postman these can help https://developer.mypurecloud.com/api/rest/postman/index.html and https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#bearer-token.

Comment: Hello there, I want to know If I send my key using API KEY under authoriztion in postman. Is it visible in frontend of the app?